# How to backup and restore specific tables in an HSQLDB database with Java code

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I want to backup specific tables in an HSQLDB database. We have 50+ tables in our database, but I want approximately 12 of those to be backed up and then restored, including data (not table structure only).

I want to achieve this using Java JDBC code. It would be great if I can specify some table names in the command, and I get the data as well as the table structure (DDL) in the file.

From the [HSQLDB docs](https://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_backup), I can see that it's possible to backup the entirety of the database in a `.tar` or `.tar.gz` file. But that's not our requirement.

Here are some commands I have tried:

1. `PERFORM EXPORT SCRIPT FOR DATABASE`
2. `PERFORM EXPORT SCRIPT FOR TABLE <table name> DATA`
3. `SCRIPT`

Comment: Sysadmin tasks like this are normally done with scripting. Why use Java at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also the PERFORM EXPORT SCRIPT FOR TABLE ... and PERFORM IMPORT SCRIPT DATA .. commands. The first command can export the contents of a single table as SQL statements. The second command can import the contents of a saved export.

See the Guide: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_data_management_statements

Comment: `PERFORM EXPORT SCRIPT FOR TABLE` command backs up only the data. How can I get the structure for that table only? Also, these commands will work on a table-by-table basis. How can I specify multiple table names at once?

Comment: Write a Java program to read a saved script file and copy the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for selected tables to another file.